# Wildfly and JBoss EAP equivalent versions

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, wildfly-26

I recently started working on the wildfly migration and this is completely new for me.
I have searched on the web but did not find relevant data,
Here I need the list of the wildfly and their equivalent JBoss versions. so, I can choose the dependencies accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a Red Hat account there is a listing in the [knowledge base](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21906). For a list of components in JBoss EAP there is a public [listing](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673).